# find all keys for a given value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to port the code from [coding for crosswords](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzGKCXSeHjDRSmpX9SmQ1fw/videos) from C++ to Python.

I have a dictionary where the keys are 12000 english words and the values for each key is a list of possible combinations of the key with missing letter. For example, the key-value pairs for "DOG" and "DAD" are:

```
my_dic = {
    "DOG": ["DOG", "DO-", "D-G", "D--", "-OG", "--G", "-O-", "---"],
    "DAD": ["DAD", "DA-", "D-D", "D--", "-AD", "--D", "-A-", "---"],
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to create a sort of "hash table" for which, given a value, it will return all possible keys that will match. For example, if I ask for "D--", the function will return "DOG", and "DAD".

I can flatten all values and add the key to a list using a list comprehension, but is it the fastest method?

```
def find_word(s):
    my_keys = []
    tmp = [k,v for sublist in list(my_dic.values() for k,v in sublist]
    if s in tmp:
        my_keys.append(k)
    return my_keys
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just return a [**list comprehension**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), note this has the same time complexity as your current solution:

```
my_dict = {
    "DOG": ["DOG", "DO-", "D-G", "D--", "-OG", "--G", "-O-", "---"],
    "DAD": ["DAD", "DA-", "D-D", "D--", "-AD", "--D", "-A-", "---"]
}

def find_keys(search_value):
    return [
        key
        for key, values in my_dict.items()
        if search_value in values
    ]
```

If you will be repeatedly looking for keys in `my_dict` you might want to make a data structure that is the reverse mapping for `O(1)` lookup time using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), Note the creation of this reverse mapping `dict` is `O(M*N)` where `M` is the number of keys and `N` is the length of the longest list, so you should only do it once, and not inside the `find_keys` function itself:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = {
    "DOG": ["DOG", "DO-", "D-G", "D--", "-OG", "--G", "-O-", "---"],
    "DAD": ["DAD", "DA-", "D-D", "D--", "-AD", "--D", "-A-", "---"]
}

my_dict_reversed = defaultdict(list)
for key, values in my_dict.items():
    for value in values:
        my_dict_reversed[value].append(key)

def find_keys(search_value):
    return my_dict_reversed[search_value]
```

**Example Usage:**

```
>>> find_keys("D--")
['DOG', 'DAD']
```

Lastly, as a side note, you may want to consider passing in the `dict` as an argument to `find_keys` rather than call a globally declared variable `dict` for reusability, But I believe that is going outside of the scope of the original question.

Comment: Thx a lot. It's really fast!

Comment: This is still a linear-time look.

Comment: @ShashSinha you don't have to?

Comment: Got there in the end XD... I used `defaultdict` so as to not repeat your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a `dict` *is* a hash table, but it maps keys to values. You want the *reverse* mapping:

```
my_dic = {
    "DOG": ["DOG", "DO-", "D-G", "D--", "-OG", "--G", "-O-", "---"],
    "DAD": ["DAD", "DA-", "D-D", "D--", "-AD", "--D", "-A-", "---"],
}

rev_dic = {}
for k, vs in my_dic.items():
    for v in vs:
        rev_dic.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

Then use this dict:

```
print(rev_dic["D--"])
```

Of course, **don't do the reverse mapping every time you want to make this sort of query**, create this dict separately and ahead of time and keep re-using it.

So:

```
def find_words(s, default=None):
    return rev_dic.get(s)
```

Or, you could raise an error, maybe a ValueError:

```
def find_words(s):
    try:
        return re_dic[s]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError("Some helpful message")
```

Now your look-up is constant time (of course, you've used auxiliary space, a class trade-off).